# Authenticating RESTful API

Tags: php, android, rest, restful-authentication

I'm sure you've seen similar questions many times on stackoverflow and I've had my share of browsing through many of them unsuccessfully, without finding a specific answer I was looking for.

So, my question is: I'm developing a private-facing API that will be consumed by my mobile application and I am having difficulties choosing a specific authentication option and its implementation.

I've gone through many articles telling me the pros of using a HMAC-SHA1 digest authentication and some praising oAuth-based authentication for REST API's and frankly it has made me more confused as it is my first time developing a RESTful API.

What I need to ask is how can I choose which authentication method to use and why? I know that using HMAC or digest authentication creates an extra overhead on the server as a request would be process in two stages:

1. Client requesting a resource to the server,
2. Server replying back with a 401 status code and a bunch of header parameters like nonce, realm and whatnot,
3. Client resending the same request but now with creating a hash of the request body and doing further processing on the previously sent parameters.

Now more questions:

1. Why this complex? Wouldn't it decrease the efficiency of the server by half and increase bandwith overhead on the server?
2. How do I share a secret between the server and the app without having the key or the hash to be stored somewhere in the application (a file or a database maybe). Wouldn't doing that give any user who has a rooted phone access to the resource files and even SQLlite database, tables, and its data inside?

As you might have gathered, I'm pretty confused right now and would really appreciate if you could set me in the right direction on this.
Thank you.

**Edit**: I will be using SSL/HTTPS to communicate between the server and client.

Comment: `two stages` : not necessarily, you can use `pre-emptive authentication` and send the credentials before the server asks for them, but works only with `basic`, I think. Also, the overhead is not that big. The first request is filtered early, and little processing is done there.

Comment: `shared secret key`: if the key is embedded in the app, or fetched by the app at some point, then it cannot be considered secret or safe.

Comment: Basic authentication seems.. basic but that would require me to store a hash password on the app itself, again vulnerable to theft, and send it every time I make a request. I'd like a more secured approach like HMAC authentication or perhaps a custom solution. But I get confuse when I think about signing (hashing) a request on client end using a public API key and then repeating the process on server to match the hashes. Isn't it username/password matching case all over again?

Comment: ant authentication would require storing the password/hash/key/... on the device. Even OAuth requires storing the token on the device.

Comment: I consider that it's ok if the device itself can, if hacked into through user action (such as rooting) lead to the authentication of the user being revealed, as long as it does not concern the other users. In that sense, storing the password or a hash of the password would be ok, but the private key that all my users use, no so.

Comment: All right. Then how do I ensure that the request coming to the server is from an authenticated user and not someone who just acquired the key from the app resources and signing the requests using that key?
Moreover, how to authenticate and implement a key exchange mechanism in the first place?

Comment: So you're saying is that I keep a private key associated with a user in the app and use that key to sign/hash further communication with that key? Am I correct?

Comment: In your situation, I would consider using HTTP Basic authorization, with pre-emptive authentication if server overhead worries you. You'd have to store the password on the device, but that's ok if you consider that a/ your communications are only in https b/ only your user himself can allow the password to be revealed, by rooting the device.

Comment: moreover, I would try to structure my project (both on client and server) so that the authentication mechanism can be replaced without too much work, in case you decide to switch to another mechanism.

Comment: Ahan. And by pre-emptive authentication you mean sending username and hashed password or API key and other parameters(in case of digest authentication) with every request to the server, right?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to build the mechanism in a way that switching them doesn't require much work on both the server and client side.

Comment: right. pre-emptive means that you don't first send a request, receive the challenge, then resend the request with authorization header, but immediately send the header. The server has to be configured to accept that.

Comment: Got it! So whenever every request to a protected resource is received at the server (in my case, everything is a protected resource except registration of a new user), the server automatically looks for authentication parameters, carry out the authentication (match records from DB etc) and then continue with the execution of the original request.

Comment: What are your application's security requirements? Start there, and find an approach that fits them.

Comment: I'm not dealing with sensitive data like private information or financial records so it is not imperative to take extraordinary measures for security. But I'd still want the app to have enough security to only allow accessing and updating data for authenticated users who've made a request using the application and application alone.

Answer (score 0):

A secure web service must provide following 4 services:

- Authentication: A secure protocol should allow the server to verify
  that the client has been authenticated within a certain time period.
  Moreover, any client should not be able to forge a valid
  request/token.
- Confidentiality: The contents of a secure request is intended only
  for the server to read.
- Integrity: A secure protocol should allow a server to detect whether
  a request/token has been modified.
- Anti-replay: In the case that an attacker replays a stolen token, a
  secure protocol should be able to detect that the token/request is
  invalid.

To grant these four services, SSL/TLS is a must. This will grant the client that the server that it is talking to is the good one and will provide confidentiality.

To authenticate the client, the server need to hold a list of valid clients or users. To be very honest, the way of authentication that you use, will depend on your requirements:

- HTTP Basic: under TLS is a valid option, it is very fast. Better for
  systems that need performance.
- HTTP Digest: To be truth, it is more or less so secure like basic
  HTTP as it is vulnerable to MiM attacks, therefore only valid if TLS.
  It is slower.
- Your own token (like Amazon) or some other token implementation
  (OAuth...): Why not, it is more complex, you will need to install a
  secret key on the client (difficult deployment) but probably will be
  the most secure option...

In my opinion, you would anyway have to use TLS, and the management of the keys in the client may be a pain and usually is vulnerable.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Rafa. Your explanation of the theoretical side of a secured REST API is good but can you shed more light on the practical implementation? In cases like Digest or token-based authentication, I have to store a generated key on client's end (a resource file or database). Both are vulnerable to theft if the user knows how to decompile the app and get access to those keys. They can then pretend to be an authenticated client and send request on its behalf.

Comment: I agree, that is why I usually use http basic always on TSL. Sometimes I even create my own headers to authenticate.

Comment: You mean you write customized authentication methods?

Comment: If necessary, yes. With Service Stack I use filters. Other frameworks allow you to implement authentication as well. Most frameworks give you authentication out of the box, you only need to configure it. PLease check the documentation of the framework that you're using.

Comment: I'm not using any framework and I've designed customized methods and authentication routines for the app. The only thing that worries me is keeping the method of making this hash on the mobile app that makes it vulnerable to extraction by decompiling the code and understanding how I'm forming up certain hashes to be authenticated at server end.

Comment: You're right, that is way I don't use any kind of complex hashing on the client: it is insecure in any way. It is better to rely on simple standards and TLS. Anything that you put on the client will compromise you.

Comment: Please elaborate 'simple standards'?

Comment: http authentication (basic, digest...)